# Permutation brute force vs Selection brute force algorithm. When to use what?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking, brute-force

Which to use and when? And what are the advantages of one approach over the other?

Permutation brute force is the one in which at each recursion step, we can enter any of the array elements. If repeats are not allowed, we maintain a "visited" memo(as in DFS), if repeats are allowed, we don't need the "visited" memo

```
f(arr,target) -> for x in arr: f(arr,target-x)
```

Selection brute force is the one in which at each recursion step, we only enter a particular array element. If repeats are not allowed, we select the current element 0/1 times(0/1 knapsack). If repeats are allowed, we select the current element 0,1,2,... times(unbounded knapsack).

```
f(arr,i,n) -> f(arr,i+1,n)
```

I have seen that in the case of DP, if both options are available cleanly, it is better to use permutation brute force, because it creates a cleaner induction hypothesis because we dont have to involve index of supposedly "current element". Or else use the other.

But in case of backtracking, or if we need to GENERATE ALL SUBSETS, it is better to use selection brute force, because the know ordering helps eliminate the cases of repeated elements in our final answer.

I am confused about when to use what, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of one over the other.
What will you prefer and when?

Comment: You have not explained the goal of the algorithm. What is `target`? What is `n`? Why one piece of code has `target` and no `n`, while the other has the inverse? Permutations with repetitions are a thing, but that refers to the input having duplicate values, not to picking the same number an arbitrarily number of times from the input. This post mentions concepts of permutation generators, subset generators, knapsack, and the specific money change problem with either 1 piece of each coin, or unlimited of them. Currently this question is too broad.